# jQuery Animate and CSS working intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a custom chat UI with jQuery/CSS and API.AI

I have an overlay that shows up when API.AI returns chat suggestions in the API call. I have these two functions controlling the overlay's visibility on the page.

```
function hideSuggestions(){
    $("#suggestionOverlay").animate({"bottom":"-50px","opacity":"0"},function(){
        $("#suggestionOverlay").css({"display":"none"});
    });
}

function showSuggestions(){
    console.log("triggered");
    $("#suggestionOverlay").css({"display":"block"}).queue(function() {
        $("#suggestionOverlay").animate({"bottom":"50px","opacity":"1"});
       $(this).dequeue();
    });
}
```

The `showSuggestions()` function is working very intermittently though. Sometimes it shows properly, other times the overlay has properties `display: none; and bottom: 50px` or `bottom: -50px and display: block;` which means it doesn't show at all. The `console.log("triggered")` always works though.

I tried the more basic variant without queueing/dequeueing but this seemed to have the same effect.

The `showSuggestions()` function is present in the following block of code:

```
function send()
{
    var url = "api.php?q="+encodeURI($("#q").val(););
    hideSuggestions();
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        if(data['suggestions'].length != 0)
        {
            var suggestionsHTML = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < data['suggestions'].length; i++)
            {
                suggestionsHTML = suggestionsHTML+'<div class="suggestion">'+data['suggestions'][i]+'</div>';
            }
            $("#suggestionsParent").html(suggestionsHTML);
            showSuggestions();
        }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `.stop()` function at the start

It stop your animation when you call another animation too quickly

Here's the code, try to remove `.stop()` function and you can see the difference

```js
function hideSuggestions(){
    $("#suggestionOverlay").stop().animate({"bottom":"-50px","opacity":"0"},function(){
        $("#suggestionOverlay").css({"display":"none"});
    });
}

function showSuggestions(){
    $("#suggestionOverlay").stop().css({"display":"block"}).queue(function() {
        $("#suggestionOverlay").animate({"bottom":"50px","opacity":"1"});
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
} 

$(document).on("click","#button1",function(){
  hideSuggestions();
});

$(document).on("click","#button2",function(){
  showSuggestions();
});

$(document).on("click","#button3",function(){
  hideSuggestions();
  showSuggestions();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="suggestionOverlay">suggestionOverlay</div>
<button id="button1">hide</button>
<button id="button2">show</button>
<button id="button3">hide/show quickly</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to be the issue.